# Php error on new server

Tags: php, function, parameters

Hi i have a new server runing php 5.4 on rackspace and there is errors con my code 
i cannot do this becouse its giveme a error:

```
if(empty($basics->conversions*100) || empty($basics->activations))
```

this is the problem: `($basics->conversions*100);`
i have to do `$vr = $basic->conversions*100;`
`if(empty($vr))` but i have this all over my code and i cannot fix it

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '*', expecting ')' in ***
```

the other error is when using a function returning an array and accesing that array insted of assign it to a variable example:

```
getReports($date, $todate)['utm'];
```

this gives me error.
but if i do:

```
$arrReportes = getReports($date,$todate);
$arrReports['utm'];
```

Works perfectly why ? can you helpme i cannot find any on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

> Prior to PHP 5.5, **empty() only supports variables; anything else will
>   result in a parse error**. In other words, the following will not work:
>   empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

This explains why your first error is occurring - `empty()` just doesn't let you pass an expression to it like you are doing in the version of php you said you are running (5.4).

The second error should really have been put in a separate question. In theory what you are trying to do should be possible since php 5.4 -

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a
>   function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a
>   temporary variable.

(from http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

- but you claim to be running 5.4 so I'd imagine there's an issue somewhere else. I'd double check the version of php you're running, and ensure your code isn't at fault there too. You didn't specify what error you were getting, so it could well be that the returned array is null, or anything.